# Why do notification SOUNDS make the phone VIBRATE?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

If I create a regular notification without sound, it works correctly.  But if I add a sound, it vibrates.  This is illogical so I don't understand it.

Here is an example of the code that works correctly (doesn't vibrate)

```
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0))
            .setOngoing(false);

    builder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE);
    builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    builder.setLights(0xFF00FF00, 1000, 0);
    Uri theUri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    //builder.setSound(theUri);
    builder.setContentText("Android sucks");
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(FOREGROUND_ID, builder.build());
```

Here is the code that causes the phone to vibrate.  Notice that vibration is NOT set in my notification:

```
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0))
            .setOngoing(false);

    builder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE);
    builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    builder.setLights(0xFF00FF00, 1000, 0);
    Uri theUri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    builder.setSound(theUri);
    builder.setContentText("Go buy an iPhone");
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(FOREGROUND_ID, builder.build());
```

Call me irrational, but when I want the sound I'll set the sound and when I want vibration, I'll set the vibration.  If I want both, I'll set both.  So why is it that when I set the sound, I automatically get vibration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
            long[] nullify = {0,0,0};
            builder.setVibrate(nullify);
```

Although it lead to a number of additional frustrating anomalies.  There are seven audio streams.  They are:

```
    STREAM_RING;
    STREAM_NOTIFICATION;
    STREAM_ALARM;
    STREAM_MUSIC;
    STREAM_DTMF;
    STREAM_SYSTEM;
    STREAM_VOICE_CALL;
```

Now, if I had to choose which stream I thought the notification sound would use, which stream do you think I'd guess?  You are correct, I expect it to use STREAM_NOTIFICATION.  What stream does it use?  STREAM_SYSTEM.  So if I want to be able to control the volume of my notification, I have to set the volume for STREAM_SYSTEM.  But that of course has unwanted side effects like now that I changed that setting you can hear an audible sound when I click "like" on something in the facebook app, for example.

Android is crazy messed up.